# Local server by PythonJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, server

I downloaded this 
[demo server](https://github.com/PythonJS/pythonjs-demo-server-nodejs).
I follow the instruction, so

> First, git clone this repo, and then run: npm install python-js. Now you are ready to run the server, run: ./run-demo.js and then open your browser to localhost:8080.

Unfortunately I can't run run-demo.js beacuse I have this error

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Line:   1
Character:  1
Error:  Invalid character
Code:   800A03F6
Source:     Microsoft JScript - compilation error
```

I try to run this by node.js console but have only "..." and nothing happend.

This is code of run-demo.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var fs = require('fs')
//var pythonjs = require('../PythonJS/pythonjs/python-js')
var pythonjs = require('python-js')
var pycode = fs.readFileSync( './server.py', {'encoding':'utf8'} )
var jscode = pythonjs.translator.to_javascript( pycode )
eval( pythonjs.runtime.javascript + jscode )
```

Any ideas? I want to run local server and use PythonJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else will be looking for solution, here is it:

```
node run-demo.js
```

Simple as... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `#` is a valid character in Javascript. If the `run0demo.js` file is being delivered to your browser, it certainly won't know what to make of the shebang (`#!`) line, which is used by the UNIX kernel to determine which executbale should be used to process the file.

Comment: How can i run this run-demo.js on Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm not a node developer, but I imagine if you make the file executable with `chmod -x run-demo.js`  you should be able to run it with `./run-demo.js`. [This stackexchange question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script) might help.

Comment: That wasn't a problem. I added solution